failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref efd37489 "/pnpm-lock.yaml": not found
I am trying to run my Web_portal, Admin_portal and backend portal all together in one docker container and i am getting this error
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref efd37489-e0fa-4ee9-b48e-c9ffffb53a30::0c8fvaro0vau9cbisu6cxj124: "/pnpm-lock.yaml": not found

version: '3.8'
name: 'ticket-snapper'
services:
  backend_api:
    build:
      context: ./ticket-outlet-backend-api/docker
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./ticket-outlet-backend-api:/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - ticket-outlet-network

  web_portal_user:
    build:
      context: ./ticket-outlet-web-portal/docker
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ./ticket-outlet-web-portal:/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - ticket-outlet-network

  web_portal_admin:
    build:
      context: ./ticket-outlet-admin-portal-v1/docker
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    volumes:
      - ./ticket-outlet-admin-portal-v1:/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - ticket-outlet-network

networks:
  ticket-outlet-network:
    driver: bridge

This is my docker-compose.yml and i have kept this file in my Desktop directory as my code for all the portal are at Desktop

That error message says the pnpm-lock.yaml file isn't in the docker subdirectories you've named as the build contexts.  Can you move the Dockerfiles up to the main application directories, and use those directories directly as the build context; build: ./ticket-outlet-admin-portal-v1?  Don't forget to remove the volumes: blocks that hide the image content, since otherwise you're not actually using anything in the images you're building.
